# save data in session one by one and save them altogether in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I am sending ajax request to save model in json format in a Session

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#addSubject').click(function () {
            var mydata = {
                "SubjectId": $('#subjectid').val(),
                "ObtainedGpa": $('#obtainedgpa').val(),
                "SubjectTypeId": $('#subjecttypeid').val()
            };
            var dataToPost = JSON.stringify(mydata);
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/PreviousExamInfo/SaveSubjectInfo",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: dataToPost,
                dataType: "json",

            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

this is done successfully.But the in my action i have to save them in Session.The approach is like  "Click The ADD button and save the Values in the Session, again click the ADD button and store the new values in session with the previously stored values".And after clicking the submit button all the values which is in the session will be stored in database. How can I know that the session works as I expecting?Because wher I use

> var mySession=Session["myItem"]
>    this only shows the new values not what I was added previously.Should I use Session? Or Is there anything else that I can use?

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveSubjectInfo(PreviousExamSubject previousExamSubject)
        {
            List<PreviousExamSubject> list=new List<PreviousExamSubject>();
            list.Add(previousExamSubject);
            Session["myitem"] = list;
            return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code always replaces the existing Session["myitem"] with a new list. To append instead you could do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveSubjectInfo(PreviousExamSubject previousExamSubject)
{
    List<PreviousExamSubject> list= (List<PreviousExamSubject>) Session["myitem"] ?? new List<PreviousExamSubject>();
    list.Add(previousExamSubject);
    Session["myitem"] = list;
    return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: thanks and this works but can you tell me how this line works  List<PreviousExamSubject> list= (List<PreviousExamSubject>) Session["myitem"] ?? new List<PreviousExamSubject>(); ..I don't understand it,then I will mark it as answer

Comment: a = b ?? c means that a is set equal to b if b has a a value (b != null), and if not, a will be set to c. b and c need to be of the same type, hence the casting of the Session variable. For more info about the ?? operator, please have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173224.aspx